# ionic2 modal error no data sending

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ionic2

When i use alertCtrl like this data is going to db  it's working well.

```
 addTodo(){

    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'add',
      message: 'add',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'title'
        },
        {
          name: 'kan'
        },
        {
          name: 'geos'
        },
        {
          name: 'geod'
        },
        {
          name: 'sahip'
        }

      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'İptal'
        },
        {
          text: 'Kaydet',
          handler: todo => {

                if(todo){

                    this.showLoader();

                    this.todoService.createTodo(todo).then((result) => {
                        this.loading.dismiss();
                        this.todos = result;
                        console.log("todo created");
                    }, (err) => {
                        this.loading.dismiss();
                        console.log("not allowed");
                    });

                }


          }
        }
      ]
    });

    prompt.present();

  }
```

But when i try to use modal , showloader is running but  createtodo is not  working , no data is going to db .

```
 addTodo(){

        let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(KaneklePage);

        modal.onDidDismiss(todo => {

                    if(todo){

                        this.showLoader();

                        this.todoService.createTodo(todo).then((result) => {
                            this.loading.dismiss();
                            this.todos = result;
                            console.log("todo created");
                        }, (err) => {
                            this.loading.dismiss();
                            console.log("not allowed");
                        });

                    }

      });

        modal.present();


  }
```

This is dismiss code in modalpage

```
save(): void {

    let todo = {
      title: this.title,
      kan: this.kan,
      geos: this.geos,
      geod: this.geod,
      sahip: this.sahip
    };

    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(todo);

  }
```

Comment: are you getting the data in `onDidDismiss`? did you print todo there?

Comment: Yes , i can get data in onDidDismiss i can print it , but when i try send it to db its not working .

Comment: are you getting any errors? what are you able to print in the console?

Comment: I apologize for keeping you busy, I used TEXT AREA instead of INPUT AREA in modalpage.html  i change it to input area and now it's working.